# Is There a IIS URL Rule That Stops HTTPs Upgrades?

Tags: asp.net, http, iis, https, upgrade

I have a website that absolutely has to maintain the ability to serve all content located in two specific subdirectories of the website over HTTP and not HTTPS to maintain backward compatibility for specific end users.

The other day, a user reported to me that a page they were using stopped working and after doing some initial testing and receiving more feedback from other users, it appears that the web browser(s) are now forcing all anchor tags to HTTPS if at any point the user visits a page under the current domain and that page was served over HTTPS (like the login screen that all users start at).

This has now become a very problematic issue as it has broken core features of my website for users who needed to access those two directories under HTTP at all times. As a web developer, I know that best practices say to serve everything under SSL but best practices and reality are two different things and reality says that at this point in time, that is not a possibility.

I have found a potential work around for my Chrome browser users which requires the user to modify a browser flag and while the process to do so is pretty straight forward, normal every day users should not be tampering with the browsers internal settings. For Firefox, I have hit a dead end.

I've been following a report by another person on the Chromium bug site (https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1492782&q=http%20anchor&can=2) which describes the issue at hand. One of the posts' responses (#7), indicated the following:

**"If a site does not support HTTPS the recommendation is to either close the connection (don't respond on port 443) or serve an HTTP 30X redirect back to HTTP. Both of those will cause the HTTPS upgrade attempt to fallback to HTTP. Upgrading in-page links is explicitly intended behavior."**

So I tried to create a IIS URL Rule shown below that says if the request tries to hit that folder under HTTPS, to return a 404 in the hopes that the browser would honor the original anchor tags path, but to no avail as the page still loads.

```
<rule name="Override HTTP Upgrade Browser Behavior" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="https:\/\/(.*)\/httpOnlyFolder\/(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    </conditions>
    <action type="CustomResponse" statusCode="404" subStatusCode="0" statusReason="Prevent browser from forcing HTTPS" statusDescription="404 Redirect to HTTP" />
</rule>
```

Are there any ways to fix this issue either by a rule in IIS or by modifying the code behind of the ASPX pages to catch and force an HTTP only load of the page?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could try rule as shown below:

```
 <rule name="Redirect to HTTP" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
        <match url="^httpOnlyFolder\/.*" ignoreCase="true" />
        <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="on" />
        </conditions>
        <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Just would like to share with you that for the security purpose it would be batter to use the https instead of http. Try to move the content to https in future.